# How to transform the Arbitrary Rotation Matrix A to a coordinate system where the Z axis lies along the axis of rotation by Similarity Transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, classical-mechanics, similar-matrices

In Chapter 4 of the book Classical Mechanics by **Goldstein**, it was written that ***"By means of some similarity transformation, it is always possible to transform the matrix A to a system of coordinates where the z axis lies along the axis of rotation"***.

I don't understand how this is done. Can anyone please explain this to me with appropriate physical example with mathematical calculation.

Thank you in advance.

[image: Similarity Transformation]

Comment: The rotation matrix that rotates your original coordinates system such that the axis of rotation is now the $z$-axis is the matrix that performs the similarity transformation. Simple when you look up those things in wikipedia. You can work that out yourself. No need to ask for all the details by someone else here. Own efforts count. Further questions are permitted.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be the given rotation matrix expressed in the basis of the world frame.

Then the image of a point $p$ is $p'$ given by

$p' = R p$

Assume that you know or can determine the axis $a$ and angle of rotation $\theta$ of matrix $R$, and using this information, you define a coordinate system through the rotation matrix $R_1$ where R1 has its third column equal to the axis $a$, then it follows that

$p = R1 q$

where $q$ is the coordinate of the point $p$ expressed in the $R_1$ frame.

Matrix $R_1$ takes the form

$R1 = [u_1, u_2, a ]$

where $a \cdot u_1 = a \cdot u_2 = u_1 \cdot u_2 = 0 $, and

$ u_1 \times u_2 = a , \ a \times u_1 = u_2 , \ a \times u_2 = - u_1 $

Therefore, now, the image $p'$ can expressed as

$ p' = R_1 q' $

and also,

$ p' = R p = R R_1 q $

Therefore,

$q' = R_1^{-1} R R_1 q = R_1^T R R_1 = R' q $

where $R' = R_1^T R R_1 $

This defines the similarity relation between $R$ and $R'$.

From Rodrigues' rotation matrix formula, the rotation matrix R is given by

$R = a a^T + (I - a a^T) \ \cos \phi + S_a \ \sin \phi $

where $S_a v = a \times v $ for any vector $v$.

It follows that,

$R R_1 = [ a a^T + (I - a a^T) \ \cos \phi + S_a \ \sin \phi ][ u_1, u_2, a] $

This evaluates to

$ R R_1 = [ u_1 \ \cos \phi + u_2 \ \sin \phi , u_2 \ \cos \phi - u_1 \ \sin \phi , a ] $

Hence,

$R_1^T R R_1 = \begin{bmatrix} u_1^T \\ u_2^T \\ a^T \end{bmatrix} [ u_1 \ \cos \phi + u_2 \ \sin \phi , u_2 \ \cos \phi - u_1 \ \sin \phi , a ] $

and this evaluates to

$R' = R_1^T R R_1   = \begin{bmatrix}  \cos \phi  &&     - \sin \phi  &&    0 \\
 \sin \phi && \cos \phi &&    0 \\
   0  &&            0     &&    1 \end{bmatrix} $

which is what we wanted to show. Note that matrix $R_1$ is not unique.